# Laravel: Job batch exits because of SQL error

Tags: php, laravel

When running jobs inside a batch, if too many jobs fail, I get the exception

String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'failed_job_ids'

This is caused because the default migration that the command php artisan queue:batches-table generates lists the failed_jobs_id as a TEXT type, which has some limitations. Can I change the mysql column type to LONGTEXT?

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html), "These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold"

Comment: I don't see why not. Go ahead and try it.

Comment: Yup! I'd create a migration to update that column type (for clarity and housekeeping purposes), but otherwise it should be fine. Note: `TEXT` can store 65535 bytes/characters, `MEDIUMTEXT` can store 16777215 and `LONGTEXT` can store 4294967295. Maybe don't jump all the way to `LONGTEXT` unless you're sure you need it. Or, considering processing jobs in smaller batches?